# What is the best experinces to structure a Django project for scale?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django is great. But as we add new features, as our dev team grows, the software needs to be stable on production, things can get quite messy.

We are going to want some common patterns, derived from experience, on how to structure your Django project for scale and longevity.

What is your suggestion?

Indeed, there are many models and patterns for development, but we want to know your experiences.

Edit : I found this and I think it is helpful, but my question is, what does the experience say?
https://maktabkhooneh.org/mag/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Django-Design-Patterns-and-Best-Practices.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can list the important points below that you should follow in large-scale projects

```
Organize your apps inside a package

Explicitly name your database tables

Avoid GenericForeignKey

Keep migrations safe

Squash your migrations

Reduce migration friction

Avoid Fat Models

Be careful with signals

Avoid using the ORM as the main interface to your data

Don’t cache Django models
```

Be sure to read the following article to read each of the above
https://medium.com/@DoorDash/tips-for-building-high-quality-django-apps-at-scale-a5a25917b2b5